# Database Exception: Column not found

Tags: craft3

I have been updating my plugins and Craft CMS to 3.2. When trying to login to the admin I get the following error:

It seems to be stumbling over a field that should be in place. The field type is "Map" provided by the Map plugin. What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Thanks

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'content.field_mapLocation' in 'field list'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`fieldLayoutId`, `elements`.`uid`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_sites`.`slug`, `elements_sites`.`siteId`, `elements_sites`.`uri`, `elements_sites`.`enabled` AS `enabledForSite`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`authorId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`title`, `content`.`field_jobNotes`, `content`.`field_personBiography`, `content`.`field_careersForm`, `content`.`field_caseStudyClientName`, `content`.`field_caseStudyClientQuote`, `content`.`field_caseStudyClientAttribution`, `content`.`field_caseStudyUrl`, `content`.`field_eventEndDate`, `content`.`field_eventCost`, `content`.`field_eventLocation`, `content`.`field_eventUrl`, `content`.`field_featured`, `content`.`field_fundDescription`, `content`.`field_fundUrl`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityAim`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityCpiEnquiriesCloseDate`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityCurrency`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityDescription`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityFunder`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityFundingType`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityLimit`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityProjectStartDate`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityResultDate`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityScope`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityShowStartDate`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunitySubmissionDate`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityURL`, `content`.`field_fundingOpportunityValue`, `content`.`field_headOffice`, `content`.`field_globalHeaderMeta`, `content`.`field_imageVariants16by9`, `content`.`field_imageVariants16by9Parallax`, `content`.`field_imageVariantsThumb`, `content`.`field_intro`, `content`.`field_jobApplicationType`, `content`.`field_jobReferenceNo`, `content`.`field_jobSalary`, `content`.`field_personJobTitle`, `content`.`field_latitude`, `content`.`field_locationAddress`, `content`.`field_locationPhone`, `content`.`field_logoVariants`, `content`.`field_longitude`, `content`.`field_mapLocation`, `content`.`field_partnerDescription`, `content`.`field_partnerUrl`, `content`.`field_personPostNominals`, `content`.`field_previewDescription`, `content`.`field_projectEndDate`, `content`.`field_projectNo`, `content`.`field_projectStartDate`, `content`.`field_projectUrl`, `content`.`field_seoSettings`, `content`.`field_eventStartDate`, `content`.`field_subtitle`, `content`.`field_caseStudyChallenge`, `content`.`field_caseStudyOutcome`, `content`.`field_jobPerson`, `content`.`field_jobRole`, `content`.`field_thoughtLeadershipCampaign`, `content`.`field_timelineText`, `content`.`field_timelineUrl`, `content`.`field_timelineYear`, `content`.`field_personTitle`, `structureelements`.`root`, `structureelements`.`lft`, `structureelements`.`rgt`, `structureelements`.`level`, `structureelements`.`structureId`
FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `elementsSitesId`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `structureelements`.`structureId`
FROM `elements` `elements`
INNER JOIN `entries` `entries` ON `entries`.`id` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON (`content`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (`content`.`siteId` = `elements_sites`.`siteId`)
LEFT JOIN `structureelements` `structureelements` ON (`structureelements`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM `structures`
WHERE (`id` = `structureelements`.`structureId`) AND (`dateDeleted` IS NULL)))
WHERE (`elements_sites`.`siteId`=1) AND (`elements`.`id`=2) AND (`elements`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (`elements`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`draftId` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`revisionId` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `structureelements`.`lft`, `entries`.`postDate` DESC
LIMIT 1) `subquery`
INNER JOIN `entries` `entries` ON `entries`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements` `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsSitesId`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON `content`.`id` = `subquery`.`contentId`
LEFT JOIN `structureelements` `structureelements` ON (`structureelements`.`elementId` = `subquery`.`elementsId`) AND (`structureelements`.`structureId` = `subquery`.`structureId`)
ORDER BY `structureelements`.`lft`, `entries`.`postDate` DESC
```

Comment: Looks like you're running into this: https://github.com/ethercreative/simplemap/issues/173 Going to vote to close this out.

Comment: Thanks, Brad - can you provide some clarity on how to typically resolve migration issues?